# Problem in execution of custom made python scripts for RNA seq analysis

Tags: python, indexing, arguments

I am trying to use a pipeline for RNA seq which has been used by one of my colleagues. I have got in a total of 8 files. These files are 8 count files of RNA seq data. I am using less command less wth1count.txt

```
less wth2count.txt
less wth3count.txt
less wth4count.txt
less 99h1count.txt
less 99h2count.txt
less 99h3count.txt
less 99h4count.txt
and to count the number of lines for each of the 8 files the command that I use is 
wc -l wth1count.txt
wc -l wth2count.txt
wc -l wth3count.txt
wc -l wth4count.txt
wc -l 99h1count.txt
wc -l 99h2count.txt
wc -l 99h3count.txt
wc -l 99h4count.txt
```

My subsequent goal is to filter out reads that are lower than 5
and for that, I am using python scripts
nano filtercounts.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Load relevant modules

import sys

#Read in the HTseq gene count output files for each of the 8 samples
    
inputlist = [sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5], sys.argv[6], sys.argv[7] 
 
#Determine the genes with sufficient coverage
#Set up a variable to hold genes with sufficient coverage in any of the 7 samples

genelist = []

#For each HTseq file

for i in range(len(inputlist)):

    #Open it
        
    inputfile = open(inputlist[i], 'r')
        
    #For each line
        
    for line in inputfile:
        
        #Determine the number of reads/transcripts for this gene
            
        splitline = line.strip().split('\t')
            
        #Does it pass the threshold?
            
        if int(splitline[1]) >= 5: 
            
            #If so, add it to list
            
            if not splitline[0] in genelist:
                
                genelist.append(splitline[0])
                
    #Close the file
        
    inputfile.close()

#Write out the list of sufficiently expressed genes
    
outputlist = open(sys.argv[8], 'w') 

for gene in genelist:

    outputlist.write(gene + '\n')
    
outputlist.close()

##Filter each of the HTseq files for only sufficiently expressed genes across our samples
#For each HTseq file
    
for i in range(len(inputlist)):
    
    #Open it
    
    inputfile = open(inputlist[i], 'r')
    
    #Open an output 'filtered' file
    
    outputfile = open(sys.argv[i+9], 'w')
    
    #For each line
    
    for line in inputfile:
    
        #Determine the gene
        
        splitline = line.strip().split('\t')
        
        #Is it in our list?
        
        if splitline[0] in genelist:
            
            #If so, write out the original line
            
            outputfile.write(line)
            
    #Close the files
    
    

    inputfile.close()
        outputfile.close()
```

Problem - When I am trying to execute the script I am getting the error "index list out of range"
The full traceback is given by Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/gpfs/ycga/project/nicoli/ag2646/99H50/filtercounts.py", line 9, in 
inputlist = [sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5], sys.argv[6], sys.argv[7], sys.argv[8]]
IndexError: list index out of range.

I am also not sure where in the script I can feed the string of files as input?
Any help will be useful.

Comment: Can you include the full traceback? This will indicate which line of code has generated the exception.

Comment: The full trace back is as follows Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gpfs/ycga/project/nicoli/ag2646/99H50/filtercounts.py", line 9, in <module>
    inputlist = [sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5], sys.argv[6], sys.argv[7], sys.argv[8]]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It would be clearer to edit your question to include the traceback. That traceback means the user hasn't supplied enough arguments when calling your script.

Comment: How are you calling the scripts, it looks like it needs to be something like `python filtercounts.py <file1> <file2> ... <file14>` which is unwieldy. You could explicitly read a file with input file names and then create output filenames, or you can try something like `xargs` to generate a command line.